# How to process tab-separated files in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a file which is tab separated. The third column should be my key and the entire record should be my value (as per Map reduce concept).

```
val cefFile = sc.textFile("C:\\text1.txt")
val cefDim1 =  cefFile.filter { line => line.startsWith("1") }
val joinedRDD = cefFile.map(x => x.split("\\t")) 
joinedRDD.first().foreach { println }
```

I am able to get the value of first column but not third. Can anyone suggest me how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've done the split `x.split("\\t")` your rdd (which in your example you called `joinedRDD` but I'm going to call it `parsedRDD` since we haven't joined it with anything yet) is going to be an RDD of Arrays. We could turn this into an array of key/value tuples by doing `parsedRDD.map(r => (r(2), r))`. That being said - you aren't limited to just map & reduce operations in Spark so its possible that another data structure might be better suited. Also for tab separated files, you could use spark-csv along with Spark DataFrames if that is a good fit for the eventual problem you are looking to solve.

Comment: I am aware that we can use dataframes. But I am missing something that's basic in spark. So, I am trying to build my foundation strong. Thanks for your response. It solved my problem